# Create a list of defaultdict in python

Tags: python

I am doing the following :

```
recordList=[lambda:defaultdict(str)]
record=defaultdict(str)
record['value']='value1'
record['value2']='value2'
recordList.append(record)
for record in recordList:
    params =  (record['value'],record['value2'],'31')
```

i am getting the error :

> TypeError: 'function' object is not
>   subscriptable

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recordList is a list with 1 element which is a function.

If you replace the first line with

```
recordList = []
```

the rest will wor.

Answer (score 3):

```
recordList=[lambda:defaultdict(str)]
```

creates a list with a function that returns `defaultdict(str)`. So it's basically equivalent to:

```
def xy ():
    return defaultdict(str)

recordList = []    
recordList.append( xy )
```

As such, when you start your for loop, you get the first element from the list, which is not a list (as all the other elements you push to it), but a function. And a function does not have a index access methods (the `['value']` things).

Answer (score 1):

you're adding a lambda to `recordList`, which is of type 'function'. in the `for ..` loop, you're trying to subscript it (`record['value']`, `record['value2']`, etc)

Initialize `recordList` to an empty list (`[]`) and it will work.